# How to send multipart/form-data by using socket.io?

Tags: android, socket.io, base64, multipartform-data

Earlier I was using `base64` string for image encoding and sending to `node.js` server by using `socket.io` . But after referring some questions I came to know that base64 format is inefficient as it increases the image size by **33%** . So, is there any way to transmit data through `socket.io` by `multipart/form-data` or something like that.

Actually I'm a beginner in this `multipart/form-data` concept so please do excuse me if my question is foolish.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use Firebase or Retrofit for multipart image uploading to server.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer sir but can volley be used for this purpose ?

Comment: Volley could be used but I know Firebase was very simple to implement in my experience and Retrofit is the best library for handling multiform data in my opinion.